# Multipathing issue with Dell Powervault MD3660f

Tags: storage

I’m configuring a Dell PV MD3660f storage . Its directly attached to a R320 server (by FC HBA) and the server is running Ubuntu 12.04. For redundancy I have connected two FC HBA with both controllers of the storage and In storage I've configured both ports as a single host and mapped with a 500GB volume, but in the server showing two 500GB volume as sdc & sdd.

In this scenario, how can I get it as a single volume with redundancy?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is that you'll need some sort of multi-pathing in place:

https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/device-mapper-multipathing.html